# Is there a way with the standard linux command line tools to copy globbed files into the same directory with a new file extension?

Tags: makefile, cp

For a makefile rule I'd like to preserve some source files by duplicating them in place with a new file extension (which will be safe to modify). This will need to run on Windows too, so my ability to install new tools is limited (the Windows machine has git bash and the basic repertoire).

Is it possible to do the equivalent of `cp dir/*.txt dir/*.html` (I'm aware that this is incorrect syntax)? cp does seem to have a --backup switch, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put this in a Makefile I suggest to use make capabilities:

```
TXT  := $(wildcard dir/*.txt)
HTML := $(patsubst %.txt,%.html,$(TXT))

.PHONY: html
html: $(HTML)

$(HTML): %.html: %.txt
    cp $^ $@
```

And then:

```
$ make html
```

`$(HTML): %.html: %.txt` is a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern).